# KKT optimisation problem

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

I want to find the minimum of the following function

$$\min \limits_{x}c^{T}x$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^nx_i=1$$
$$x_i \geq 0$$

Let's define Lagrangian function:

$$L(x,\lambda,\mu) = \sum_{i=1}^nc_ix_i - \sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_ix_i + \mu\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i - \mu $$

Now, we can have KKT conditions:

$$ 
c_i - \lambda_i + \mu = 0 \\
\lambda_i x_i = 0 \\
\lambda_i \geq 0
$$

And now I'm stack and not sure how to proceed further. Any hint?

Comment: Your Lagrangian is incorrect, the constraint is $(\sum x_i)-1$ not $(\sum x_i-1)$.

Comment: @TSF fixed. However, I think it doesn't change anything, does it?

Comment: Yes, it should be $+\mu$ in the first line of your KKT conditions. I don't see where the second line comes from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a linear programming problem on a simplex which is compact, there is an optimal solution at one of the vertices.

The vertices are the standard unit vector.

Let $j$ be an index corresponding to the smallest value of $c$. Then $e_j$ is one of the optimal solution. If there are multiple such $j$'s, then their convex combination are optimal as well.

---

$$(\mu + c_i)x_i = 0$$

If $x_i \ne 0 $ and $x_j \ne 0$, then we must have $c_i = c_j$. Hence if $c_i \ne c_j$, then $x_ix_j=0$. Hence the optimal solution must take one of the $c_i$'s value, we  pick the smallest such value.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of future readers:

Let $c_\mathrm{min}$ be the smallest element of $c$ and let $i_\mathrm{min}$ be the index of this element. We have:
\begin{align}
c_1x_1&\ge c_\mathrm{min} x_1\\
c_2x_2&\ge c_\mathrm{min} x_2\\
&\dots\\
c_nx_n&\ge c_\mathrm{min} x_n.
\end{align}
Summing up the above, we obtain $c^Tx\ge c_\mathrm{min}(x_1+x_2+\dots+x_n) = c_\mathrm{min}$.

On the other hand, if $x_{i_\mathrm{min}} = 1$ and $x_i = 0 \ \forall i\neq i_\mathrm{min}$ then equality occurs: $c^Tx = c_\mathrm{min}$. We conclude that the minimum is $c_\mathrm{min}$.