# KKT conditions for linear program where $\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i=1$

Tags: convex-optimization, linear-programming, karush-kuhn-tucker

I want to find the optimal $x$ for the optimization problem: minimize $c^Tx$ subject to $x\geq0$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i=1$?

I have calculated:

1. $c_i-\lambda_i+v=0$
2. $\sum x_i=1$
3. $\lambda_ix_i=0$
4. $x_i\geq0 , \lambda_i\geq0$

I have also found that the minimum value will be the minimum value of vector $c$, as $c^Tx\geq c_{min}$ (as stated here [KKT optimisation problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4133314/kkt-optimisation-problem) ).
How do i proceed to determine the optimal $x$?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You might think about what you mean by "the minimum value of $c$"?  Might there be several entries with the same smallest value?

Comment: This particular problem can be solved more simply by basic reasoning. Show a particular $x$ can easily achieve $c_{min}$, then show you cannot go lower.

Comment: Yes, there may be several entries with the same smallest value. I guess the solution can always be a point that has 1 in the same index where $c$ is minimum and that will be optimal. This holds even if $c_{min}$ appears in multiple entries, but in that case $x_*$ is not unique. For example, if for $n=2$ we have $c=\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$ then $x_*=\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$, whereas if $c=\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$ then $x_*$ can be any combination of $x_1,x_2$ that sum to 1.